# How to create hyperlinks for all files in a directory?

Tags: php, file

I was trying to enlist all the files which are in a directory, and i have done this, but i want to link those file names with their paths too but not getting the same result as u want.

php

```
if(isset($_GET['alls'])){
        $session = $_GET['session'];
        $subject = $_GET['subject'];
        $dirh = $session.'/'.$subject.'/';
        if ($handle = opendir($dirh)) {

            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

                if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

                    echo "<a href='$dirh.'/'.$entry'> $entry\n </a>";
                }
            }

            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I seriously hope that you're not putting that on a publicly accessible host, because it's about as insecure as you can get.

Comment: am getting a filename with link to just $dirh and i want it to $dirh/filename.ext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I think The problem may concatenation

Try like this

echo "<a href='".$dirh."/".$entry."'>".$entry."</a><br/>";
```